# Magento 2 : Minimum Cart Value for Certain Category

Tags: magento2, cart

We need to setup a rules to ensure below is satisfied.

- When an item is added only from category x then minimum cart price should be set to 25
- When an item is added from category x and also has items from other categories then the minimum cart value should be set to 100.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, I tried setting up cart rules but didn't helped me. Any idea or inputs will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this can not be done using rules, you will have to create a custom module.

Magento has core functionality for setting Minimum Order amount for the whole cart, not limited to a certain category.

> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales-> Sales -> Minimum Order Amount

[image]

When developing a custom module for this, it might make sense to reuse parts of this functionality and repurpose it.

Answer (score 1):

Magento default just allows you to set up maximum quantity allowed in the shopping cart of a product only. Therefore, I think that you had better look for an extension to help you overcome this issue quickly.

For example, you can try this extension

https://marketplace.magento.com/meetanshi-magento2-limit-quantity-per-category.html

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-minimum-maximum-order-quantity-per-category-extension.html